# Radio button as itemrenderer of datagrid column in flex

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, radio-button, itemrenderer, radio-group

I am having a datagrid in which for one column  i set radio button as itemrenderer.
My requirement is only one radio button have to be selected at a time.If we click a radio button all other radio buttons in the column should get deselected.

My code as follows(ManagePagesPopup.mxml)

```
<fx:Declarations>
            <s:RadioButtonGroup id="radGrp" />
</fx:Declarations><s:DataGrid id="pageDataGrid" dataProvider="{pageDetailsAc}" >
    <s:columns>
        <s:ArrayList>
            <s:GridColumn  headerText="Select" dataField="select"  itemRenderer="components.PageSelectRadioButton" ></s:GridColumn>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="pageName" headerText="Page Template Name"></s:GridColumn>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="pageType" headerText="Page Type"></s:GridColumn>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="pageSize" headerText="Page Size"></s:GridColumn>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="order" headerText="Order" editable="true" itemRenderer="components.OrderTextInput"></s:GridColumn>
        </s:ArrayList>
    </s:columns>
</s:DataGrid>
```

In the PageSelectRadioButton.mxml(item renderer) file i wrote below code

```
<s:GridItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" >


<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[       
    [Bindable]
        public var mg:ManagePagesPopup=new ManagePagesPopup();  
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

    <s:RadioButton id="selectRadio" groupName="{mg.radGrp}" />
```

Where i am doing mistake.Any help.

Answer (score 1):

Well, basically you are assigning a different radio button group for each item renderer, because you are instantiating a new ManagesPopUp for each item renderer.

Answer (score 0):

Add an inline itemrenderer to make this work as follows:-

```
<s:GridColumn  headerText="Select" dataField="select" >
  <s:itemRenderer>
    <fx:Component>
     <s:GridItemRenderer>
      <s:RadioButton id="selectRadio" group="{outerDocument.radGrp}" />
     </s:GridItemRenderer>
    </fx:Component>
  </s:itemRenderer>
</s:GridColumn>
```